# Android : ImageButton Width & Height

Tags: java, android, height, width, imagebutton

I have ImageButton that has a scr from an image I added to the drawble-hdpi folder called imgholder, this image Width = 96pix and Height = 96px

but when I check on the Height and Width for the ImageButton in its click event I get 128!

Why is that? where did the extra came from and how to resolve this so the ImageButton has same width as the src image. 
Thanks

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ibAddImage1"
    android:src="@drawable/imgholder"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvAddReviseCaption"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"px" changes device to device.
You should use dp for layout_width and layout_height 
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"

Comment: I did not hard code any of the width or height, the image it self is 96x96 pix.

Comment: 128 can be size in dp of the image. So your image size can (96X96)px = (128X128)dp